# android - using apache package : org.apache.http

Tags: android, apache

I am trying to write some SSL related code in Android Studio, and I noticed that I could use the class `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` out of the box.

1) Does this package ship with Android's SDK, or did Android Studio do something extra to make it available ?

2) In the import, I can see :

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
```

How can I check which version of this class am I using ? It seems to have several [versions](http://grepcode.com/search?query=org.apache.http.client.HttpClient&start=0&entity=type&n=).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the standard Android SDK http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html
You could also have a look at this link to see which version is used http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/ (in 4.4.2 the version is 4.0.1)